# javascript rickshaw display number

Tags: numbers, rickshaw

I am using javascript  d3/rickshaw to plot, and display numbers,

right now I have numbers like   169779279.13,  which is not easy to understand,

is there anyway to display the number  169779279.13 as  "170 million", which is more understoodable?

here is the example I am using:

http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/examples/multi.html

when you mouse over, you can see the numbers, but if the number is too big, I will encounter the problem I mentioned above.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is: use a formatter for you HoverDetail

```
var hoverDetail2 = new Rickshaw.Graph.HoverDetail({
    graph: yourChart,
    xFormatter: function(x) {Calculate Your Stuff Here},
    yFormatter: function(y) {Calculate Your Stuff Here}
});
```

Just make sure to return a value in your x- and yFormatter method. This should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

use the inbuild function for such things like this one

```
Rickshaw.Fixtures.Number.formatKMBT
```

I used this function to format values on y-axis, maybe this can help you if I am not wrong